# Symfony Guzzle inject differents clients to autowired services

Tags: php, dependency-injection, guzzle, symfony-3.3

I want to inject guzzle client in my services, it works very well for one client.

```
services.yml
// ....
GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface: "@eight_points_guzzle.client.client1"
```

When I inject it into my client, it is correctly configured
But !
I have two differents clients in my config to inject within services.
I have tested to create a class for a specific configured client which extends the main Client like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service\Guzzle;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ClientApi extends Client
{

    /**
     * ClientApi constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}
```

And I inject the configuration like this :

```
services.yml
// ...
AppBundle\Service\Guzzle\ClientApi: "@eight_points_guzzle.client.api"
```

But every time  I try to inject it in another autowired service like this :

```
MyClass{
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $twig, ClientApi $clientApi)
    {
        $this->twig         = $twig;
        $this->guzzleClient = $clientApi;
    }
}
```

It returns me this error :

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to AppBundle\Service\MyClass::__construct()  
must be an instance of AppBundle\Service\Guzzle\ClientApi,
instance of GuzzleHttp\Client given, ....
```

any help will be welcome